# Set character_set_results UTF8 in MySQL my.cnf

Tags: mysql, utf-8, charset

how can I set the Variable character_set_results from latin1 to uft8? I thought it would be enough to add the following variable in my.cnf:

```
default-character-set=utf8
```

But it not seem so:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set_%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Does anybody have an idea how I can set character_set_results to utf8?

Answer (score 4):

The character set is negotiated between the client and the server on connect.

To prevent this and force the client and thus the server to use your configured character set:
`[mysqld]`
`skip-character-set-client-handshake=1`
`default-character-set=utf8`

Comment: I want to marry you.

Answer (score 1):

with this settings it works: 
   `[mysqld]`
   `skip-character-set-client-handshake=1`
   `default-character-set=utf8`

Greetings
Marc

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,202533,205027#msg-205027):

> It seems that the character-set-results and character-set-connection can't be set in the [mysqld] part of the config file. You have to put them in the [client] part.

I personally didn't try it.